# PostgreSQL update element in array of custom type

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, function, types

I have created simple custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE skill_progress AS
   (id uuid,
    count smallint);
```

There is column `skills` in my table `users` of type `skill_progress[]`. I need to update `count` of element in array `skill_progress[]` by specified element id. I need something like this:

```
UPDATE users SET skills['5a0574cc-66b7-4c89-9950-03a2eea0c701'].count = 10
WHERE nick = 'nick4123';
```

I have created function that does what i need but i would like to find out if there is an easier way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sp
(user_id uuid, skill_id uuid, count smallint) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    i integer;
    up integer;
    arr skill_progress[];
BEGIN
    SELECT skills INTO arr FROM users WHERE id = user_id;
    SELECT array_upper(arr, 1) INTO up;
    FOR i IN 1..up 
    LOOP
        IF arr[i].id = skill_id THEN
            UPDATE users SET skills[i].count = count WHERE id = user_id;
            RETURN 0;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 1;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I think if i create a new table, then it will be too much data duplication. For each user that table should contain few records where user id is repeated. Like this:

```
row_num  |  user_id  | skill_id  |  count
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
   1     |   1000    |   100     |    2
   1     |   1000    |   101     |    3
   1     |   1000    |   102     |    5
              . . .
```

What then is the purpose of custom types?

Comment: Seems to me that it would be trivial if `skill_progress` was a table instead of an array of a custom type. Can you explain why it's necessary to do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the table without a function:

```
update users u
set skills[rn].count = 10
from (
    select skill, rn
    from (
        select skill, row_number() over () rn
        from (
            select unnest(skills) skill
            from users
            where nick = 'nick4123'
            ) sub
        ) sub
    where (skill).id = '5a0574cc-66b7-4c89-9950-03a2eea0c701'
    ) sub
where u.nick = 'nick4123'
```

However, it is really hard to understand, why you have to make your life so much heavier. `Ids` should be `integers` (or `bigints`), `user_skills` should be a table with `user_id` referencing `users`.

---

*Update*.

Your attempt is quite natural for a programmer accustomed to handling complex internal data structures. 
A slightly different logic applies to the world of databases, 
where speed of access to data is of paramount importance, 
sometimes at the expense of redundant use of storage space.

Your tables might look like this:

```
create table users (
    user_id int primary key, 
    nick text);

create table skills (
    skill_id int primary key, 
    user_id int references users, 
    skill_count int);
```

It is a normalized data model. 
The relation between the tables is known as **one-to-many**.
This pattern is commonly used in millions of applications working with RDBMS.
This is not a good place for a detailed discussion of this issue, 
especially since you can find hundreds of good texts on **data modeling** and **normalization** in internet.

Comment: skill_id can't be primary key, because different users can have same skills, and user_id can't be primary key too, because each user can have more than one skill.